# Is there an easy built-in way to delete the first and last line of a block in vim?

Tags: vim

Quite a common task in programming is to remove the condition on the current block.

In vim, is there an easy way to delete the first line (the 'if' statement) and last line (the closing curly brace) of the current block and perhaps reindent accordingly. If there is no simple key combination for this built in, what is a straightforward way to script it?

Thinking about this a bit further, of course the condition on the if statement may span multiple lines so presumably a script is required to capture this completely. However, for my code just deleting the first and last lines would capture 95% of cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible solution

```
yiBvaBVpgv<
```

- `yiB` yanks the inner block
- `vaBV` viaually select a block, then select it linewise
- `p` paste over visually selected text
- `gv<` reselect text and de-indent

Surround like mappings aka delete surrounding block:

```
nnoremap dsB yiBvaBVpgv<
```

ib provided a shorter solution. This solution will not mutate the visual marks: `'<`, `'>`

```
diB]pkdk
```

- `diB` deletes the current inner block
- `]p` paste the newly deleted text below the end of the block but adjust the indent.
- `kdk` move up a line and then delete 2 lines up thereby deleting the start and end of the block.

Comment: Can't help but play Vim golf a little: `diBVkpgv<` or  `diB]pkdk`.  :-)

Comment: @ib: I like `diB]pkdk`. It seems to jive with me best. Nice use of `[p`. How do you like this one: `diB"_dkP<']`. I know it is not shorter, but it does not change visual marks, puts `'[` and `']` where I think they should be, and seems to keep my `:regs` clean. Probably best for a mapping like this `nmap <silent> dsB diB"_dkP<']`

Comment: @Peter:  `diB]pkdk` does not pollute marks and registers as well, except for "wrong" position of `']` mark (it also push the bordering lines to the unnamed register, but I do not think of this as a "wrong" behavior).  To fix that flaw with `']` mark, I would propose `diB"_dk]P` sequence.

Comment: @ib: `diB"_dk]P` will no have the correct indent. Anyway I agree with you the position of `']` and registers is more of my own preferences than "wrong". I have provided your `diB]pkdk` solution in my answer. Thank you for taking the time to VimGolf with me. Cheers!

Comment: @Peter:  The correctness of resulting indent after using `diB"_dk]P` depends on surrounding text, so it would not be wrong in every possible case.  Hey, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about something like `di{` `dk` `k` `"2p`? Or a little more elegant, `<i{` `di{` `dk` `k` `"2p`. Note that you have to be **inside** the block for this to work — if you're on the opening or closing lines of the block, you'll affect the surrounding block instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
command! -range=% Delete1$ <line1>delete _|<line2>delete _
```